# AttributeError: module 'users.views' has no attribute 'register'

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python and Django. Getting this error when running the server. The problem seems to be in 'urls.py' of the project.

```
File "C:\Users\Desktop\myproject\django_project\django_project\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('register/', user_views.register , name = 'register'),
AttributeError: module 'users.views' has no attribute 'register'
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register , name = 'register'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

This is register.html under users/templates/users/register.html (users is the name of the app)

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

I have also tried creating a separate urls.py for my 'users' app and adding the path there but I am getting the same error.

I am very new to programming so please excuse my inexperience.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a space after register>>> `def register (request):`

If it is not the issue please check the "views.py" for correct register function under the users folder.

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create your views here.

def register (request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow.  I edited your post to format your code blocks.  Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361) for instructions on how to do this in the future.

Comment: Why is this? I had a similar problem, added an space and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your urls.py should be like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .view.py import register

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/',register , name = 'register'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Note: if your views name is views.py

Comment: see the edits if your views name views.py then import register from views.py

Comment: No, my views is just called 'views.py', I added users to denote that it belongs to the 'users' app. Anyway I get the following error when I try this..   `from . import views as user_views`   error:   `from . import views as user_views ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'django_project'] (C:\Users\Naved\Desktop\myproject\django_project\django_project\__init__.py)`

Answer (score 0):

consider this arrange:

you have a users application in your base directory, this app has a users-views.py file that your register function is there.

then your urls.py must be like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import users-views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register , name = 'register'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

as you can see your users application has no views.py I recommend rename users-views.py to views.py and use your original urls.py.

Comment: that is what I did, my views file in users application is actually called 'views.py' and not 'user-views.py' and I am using original 'urls.py'

Answer (score 0):

Is your `users/views.py` file saved and up to date? Try stopping the server completely, `ctrl+c on windows` if it's started and double check all your files are up to date then try running the server again.